# Visual c compiler options

Tags: ida, disassembly, c, disassemblers

I ask if exist some c compiler option that can "keep" some imformation after compile that can be visible when I disassamble with IDA.

This because I need to find a particular funciton with IDA but without a "flag" is not easy.

In short I have a function called "Sbar_Draw" and I like to write inside a message for example:

```
char * test;

test = "This is the function name: Sbar_Draw/n";
```

I have already tried to do it, but after disassably with IDA this information seem lost.

There is some compile option (or other way) that allow me to easy find a function when I disassambly with IDA ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are talking about debugging information. You can use a compilation switch such as `/Zi` to generate a PDB file with debugging information which can then be used by IDA to label your functions and variables in the disassembly.

Note that some information is lost anyway: comments, preprocess or definitions, or any code or data which has been optimized out and removed.